# Multiplicative inverse and proof

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I have been tasked with finding the multiplicative inverse to [2] in Z/16. It doesn't exist, and I have proved it by saying

16 = 2*8

Is this enough? How else can I show it?

Comment: Correct, as long as you state the reason why: in rings where $1 \neq 0$, a zero divisor cannot have a multiplicative inverse.

Comment: Yes, I will emphasize this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the fact that if $R$ is a ring and $a.b=0$, then if $a$ has a left inverse, we must have $b=0$, since if $c.a=1$ then
$$
0=c.0 = c.(ab)=(ca).b=1.b=b.
$$

Thus in the ring $S=\mathbb Z/16\mathbb Z$, since $2*8=16$ and $8\neq 0$, it follows that $2$ cannot have a left inverse. (Since $S$ is commutative, having a left-inverse, a right-inverse or a two-sided inverse are all equivalent properties).

You do not need to explicitly exclude the case where $1=0$ -- if $R$ is any ring with $1=0$ then for any $a\in R$ we have $a=1.a = 0.a =0$, so that $R= \{0\}$ is the zero ring. Any ring in which you have two elements $a,b$ which are nonzero thus automatically must have $1 \neq 0$.

You could also argue that if $c\in S$ is a unit, then there is some $d \in S$ with $c.d=1\in S$. Taking $c_1,d_1$ representatives of $c,d$ in $\mathbb Z$ (say the unique integers in $\{0,1,\ldots, 15\}$ in the congruence classes of $c$ and $d$) it follows that $c_1d_1=16k+1$ for some $k \in \mathbb Z$, and hence $c_1d_1$ is odd, and so both of $c_1$ and $d_1$ must be odd. Thus $c\in S$ can be a unit only if it is of the form $2k+1$ for some $k \in S$.